# mysql - return rows in ascending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing 392871961 rows like this.

```
     p_id        r_p_id      weight
     1           2           0.223923923
     1           3           0.12923923
     1           4           0.423926924
     1           5           0.143921921
     1           6           0.323923922
     1           7           0.223923728
     .
     .
     .
     2           1           0.123923921
     2           3           0.023923922
     2           4           0.223923926
     2           5           0.323923928
     2           6           0.223923921
     2           7           0.423923921
     .
     .
     .
     3           1           0.023923925
     3           2           0.223923922
     3           4           0.123923926
     3           5           0.223923929
     3           6           0.123923921
     3           7           0.523923922
     .
     .
     .
```

p_id goes up to a little over 6000 digit. weight represents some kind of priority between p_id and r_p_id.

I have two queries like this.  A user is going to provide list of p_ids. It would be less than 10 p_ids.

first query = `select r_p_id, weight from table where p_id in (....) order by weight`

second query = `select r_p_id, (weight*0.8) as m_weight from table where p_id in (....) order by (weight * 0.8)`

I would like to combine these queries to return the r_p_id in ascending order by the sum of (weight from the first query) + (weight from the second query).

Can anybody tell me how to do it?

I'd appreciated it.

Comment: I honestly don't think I understand the question correctly. Could you show a sample result for (for example) the first section of the data you're displaying?

Comment: The first query would return the r_p_id which has the lowest weight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select t1.r_p_id, (t1.weight+t2.m_weight) as total_weight
from 
    (select r_p_id, weight from table where p_id in (....) ) as t1,
    (select r_p_id, (weight*0.8) as m_weight from table where p_id in (....)) as t2
where t1.r_p_id=t2.r_p_id
order by (t1.weight+t2.m_weight)
```

**OR** using JOIN keyword

```
select t1.r_p_id, (t1.weight+t2.m_weight) as total_weight
from 
    (select r_p_id, weight from table where p_id in (....) ) as t1 INNER JOIN
    (select r_p_id, (weight*0.8) as m_weight from table where p_id in (....)) as t2 ON t1.r_p_id=t2.r_p_id
order by (t1.weight+t2.m_weight)
```

You'l need to use JOIN between results of two queries.

**EDIT:**

Since MySQL supports `order by [alias-name]` as [dg99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731240/dg99) suggested, you can use directly `order by total_weight`

```
select t1.r_p_id, (t1.weight+t2.m_weight) as total_weight
from 
    (select r_p_id, weight from table where p_id in (....) ) as t1,
    (select r_p_id, (weight*0.8) as m_weight from table where p_id in (....)) as t2
where t1.r_p_id=t2.r_p_id
order by total_weight
```

Comment: Note that in MySQL you can `order by` aliases from the `select` statement, so you *could* change the above to `order by total_weight` for the purposes of readability.

Comment: Sure, but now other folks will probably complain your answer isn't ANSI compliant. :)

Comment: Hahahaha, No problem. I'l mention in an answer.

Comment: I'd appreciated the query. I will try it later. I hope that it resolves my headache. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Um, maybe I'm missing something, but wouldn't it just be the following?

> select r_p_id, weight, weight*0.8 AS m_weight from table where p_id in (....) order by weight

Mathmatically, you'll get the same order whether you do "order by weight" or "order by weight + 0.8*weight"

Comment: Exactly my reaction, but it _feels_ too easy :)

Comment: Yes. it does... but the second query needs to be used in the final query.

Comment: Why do you feel the second query is NOT being used in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
select r_p_id, weight, (weight*0,8) as m_weight, (weight*1.8) as total_weight 
from table where p_id in (...) order by total_weight asc
```

weight + weight * .8  = weight * 1.8, so there's a quick sum of that column.  Which of the weight columns you order by doesn't matter because they are all the same order